How can I limit the number of chrome instances puppeteer can launch?
I have an API endpoint that is doing:
    const browser = await PuppeteerHelper.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(ENDPOINT);
    const result = await page.evaluate(async (endpoint) => {
      const module = await import(`${endpoint}/resource.js`);
      const result = await module.execute();
      return result;
    }, ENDPOINT);
    await browser.close();
    return result;

Although this endpoint is "private" and should only be hit a small number of times, I am finding the server melting down and when I run top I see:
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    130 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  97.9   0.0      8,13 kswapd0
3513310 root      19  -1   33.0g 195708      0 S  29.1   0.3      7,38 chrome
3392579 root      19  -1   32.9g  58032      0 S  23.2   0.1     10,45 chrome
3265281 root      19  -1   32.9g  58056      0 S  22.6   0.1     16,18 chrome
3514710 root      19  -1   33.0g 195688      0 S  22.6   0.3      7,39 chrome
3514664 root      19  -1   33.0g 195748      0 S  19.0   0.3      7,37 chrome
3268532 root      19  -1   32.9g  58064      0 S  18.7   0.1     15,58 chrome
3263718 root      19  -1   32.9g  58276      0 S  15.9   0.1     16,43 chrome
3325663 root      19  -1   32.9g  58108      0 S  15.9   0.1     12,50 chrome
3516448 root      19  -1   33.0g 195604      0 S  15.9   0.3      7,36 chrome
3516467 root      19  -1   33.0g 195604      0 S  15.6   0.3      7,36 chrome
3269987 root      19  -1   32.9g  58072      0 S  15.3   0.1     15,51 chrome
3263675 root      19  -1   32.9g  58040      0 S  15.0   0.1     16,43 chrome
3511548 root      19  -1   33.0g 195444      0 S  14.1   0.3      7,41 chrome
3330812 root      19  -1   32.9g  58016      0 S  13.1   0.1     12,40 chrome
3796523 root      20   0       0      0      0 I  13.1   0.0   0:32.83 kworker/u32:2-flush-9:3
3325696 root      19  -1   32.9g  58068      0 S  12.2   0.1     12,51 chrome
3513362 root      19  -1   33.0g 195568      0 S  12.2   0.3      7,41 chrome
3516446 root      19  -1   33.0g 195684      0 S  11.9   0.3      7,36 chrome
3514857 root      19  -1   33.0g 195672      0 S  11.6   0.3      7,38 chrome
3511584 root      19  -1   33.0g 195552      0 S  11.3   0.3      7,42 chrome
3270066 root      19  -1   32.9g  58008      0 S   9.2   0.1     15,50 chrome
3392738 root      19  -1   32.9g  58028      0 S   9.2   0.1     10,40 chrome
3796437 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   8.9   0.0   1:22.44 kworker/u32:3-ext4-rsv-conversion
3511614 root      19  -1   33.0g 193728      0 S   8.3   0.3      7,40 chrome
3269936 root      19  -1   32.9g  58116      0 S   8.0   0.1     15,51 chrome
3266820 root      19  -1   32.9g  58056      0 S   7.0   0.1     16,06 chrome
3268384 root      19  -1   32.9g  57840      0 S   6.4   0.1     15,56 chrome
3392716 root      19  -1   32.9g  58340      0 S   6.4   0.1     10,44 chrome

to which I say.. YIKES!!!!!!!
What is the best way to throttle this and prevent puppeteer from being able to launch say no more than 10 instances of chrome?

"Best" depends on your needs. Use a global counter if you want to reject extra requests and a task queue if you want to enqueue them, maybe other techniques if they'll work better for you. Also make sure all .close() calls happen in finally blocks, otherwise you can leak browsers if they hit errors.
